# Passing the test name as a parameter

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit5

I am using Junit5 parametrizedTests and want to know if there is a possibility to generate the test name with a more advance way than to use something more advanced than @DisplayName .

The best thing for me would be having a way to use a method to generate the test name using a specific logic and the parameters that are passed to that test.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read this? https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-display-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extends `DisplayNameGenerator.ReplaceUnderscores` and use it in annotation @DisplayNameGenerator:

```
@DisplayNameGeneration(YorNameGenerator.class)
class YourTest {
    ...
}
```

Have a look at example in the [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-display-name-generator)